# Xeon processors supporting QSV, is having C226 chipset in default or not?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I need to know whether C226 chipset will be available in default with Xeon E3 or not, to enable QSV?

Referring to the link

> http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/denlow/xeon-e3-1200-v3-c266-chipset-ibd.html?wapkw=xeon

`Intel® Xeon® Processor E3-1225 v3 (8M Cache, 3.20 GHz)` and `Intel® Xeon® Processor E3-1275 v3 (8M Cache, 3.50 GHz)` have been shown over the 
block diagram. My doubt is whether C226 chipset is available in default with these processors or not?

In the link

> http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced?QuickSyncVideo=true&MarketSegment=SRV

there are many Xeon Processors supporting QSV. Among those, which one is having C226 chipet? Whether QSV supported Xeon processors will all have that chipset or we need to buy it seperately?

In the link

> streambuilder.pro/docs/how-tos/check-iqsv/

It has been shown that `Look for “Processor Graphics” line. It must contain “Intel® HD Graphics 4200”, “Intel® HD Graphics P4600” or higher value.`i.e., These graphic cards could support qsv. But in the link `ark.intel.com/search/advanced?QuickSyncVideo=true&MarketSegment=SRV`, other processor graphics are also present like they could also support qsv. So how could I select a Xeon Processor which could support QSV?

Sorry for my English and Thanks in advance

Comment: @James So do we need to buy C226 chipset seperately or it will be there with Xeon E3 12XX v3?

Comment: When you buy the motherboard you need to check the details carefully and make sure you get one listed with the C226, e.g. http://www.newegg.com/global/uk/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813182822

Comment: You don't need to buy the chipset separately, it is built into the motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused here, the chipset is built into the **motherboard** rather than the CPU.

When buying a motherboard you will find that different models may have different chipsets when compared to each other. For instance, a motherboard compatible with the particular Xeon CPU's you mentioned could use an Intel C222, C224 or a C226 chipset. The C226 motherboards will tend to have a slight price premium because you get extra features compared to the other two.

It sounds like you are looking to use StreamBuilder - there is a [support page](http://streambuilder.pro/docs/requirements/enabling-iqsv) saying that for Xeon systems you need the C226 chipset in order for QuickSync to work. So you will need to check the specifications of the motherboard before buying it, e.g. the `SUPERMICRO MBD-X10SLH-F` should work

Comment: Will C236 also support QSV? Do u have any idea about it? @James

Comment: Assuming that it is StreamBuilder that you intend to use, you may be best to contact the developers (http://streambuilder.pro/contacts/) to check which hardware is recommended and has been tested in case there are any compatibilty issues with the newer generation CPU's.

Comment: Ok. Then C226 and C236 are supporting Intel HD graphics. So they also support QSV. So do u thing C206 and C216 are not supporting Intel HD graphics (QSV)? @ James

Comment: No I am not going to use StreamBuilder. I am in need of using QSV

Comment: my doubt is, as the cpu sockets differ for C236, will a combination of E3 Xeon 12xx V5 with Intel® HD Graphics P530 and chipset C236 work out for enabling QSV or not?

Comment: Actually, looking at the specifications again , no it likely won't work. Based on this page (http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/intel-c232-c236-chipsets-xeon,news-52249.html) the C236 doesn't support the integrated graphics.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using a Xeon CPU? It would be a lot easier to get QSV working with an i5 or i7.

Comment: ya we have already did with cores. Now concentrating on Xeon

Comment: You would probably need the C226 then in order to be sure it will work.